# SQLAlchemy Boolean vs BOOLEAN

Tags: sqlalchemy

I can see that `BOOLEAN` overrides `__visit_name__`

```
class BOOLEAN(Boolean):
    __visit_name__ = 'BOOLEAN'
```

that controls visitor's method chosen by the dispatcher

```
def _compiler_dispatch(self, visitor, **kw):
    visit_attr = 'visit_%s' % self.__visit_name__
    try:
        meth = getattr(visitor, visit_attr)
```

In the case of MS SQL, the visitor is `MSSQLCompiler`, which derives from `GenericTypeCompiler`. Now, `MSSQLCompiler` overrides `visit_boolean`:

```
def visit_boolean(self, type_, **kw):
    return self.visit_BIT(type_)
```

But it does not override `visit_BOOLEAN`, so  column type `Boolean` resolves to "BIT", and `BOOLEAN` (via the superclass) resolves to "BOOLEAN", which is not a valid MS SQL type.

Why this inconsistency? Does `MSSQLCompiler` need to override `visit_BOOLEAN`, or is there something I am missing? What is the difference, conceptually, between `Boolean` and `BOOLEAN` types?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`Boolean`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.Boolean) is a [generic type](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/type_basics.html#generic-types):

> Generic types specify a column that can read, write and store a particular type of Python data. SQLAlchemy will choose the best database column type available on the target database when issuing a `CREATE TABLE` statement.

[`BOOLEAN`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.BOOLEAN) is a [SQL type](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/type_basics.html#sql-standard-and-multiple-vendor-types):

> This category of types refers to types that are either part of the SQL standard, or are potentially found within a subset of database backends. Unlike the “generic” types, the SQL standard/multi-vendor types have **no** guarantee of working on all backends, and will only work on those backends that explicitly support them by name. That is, the type will always emit its exact name in DDL with `CREATE TABLE` is issued.

There's no inconsistency, because they're different things.

Comment: So, if I want `CREATE TABLE` to work with any database (allowing SQLAlchemy to use the best type), then I need to use generic types. But if I want to control the types exactly, then I need to use SQL types.