# What's the difference between BIGINT and BigInteger in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

BigInteger

```
class BigInteger(Integer):

    """A type for bigger ``int`` integers.

    Typically generates a ``BIGINT`` in DDL, and otherwise acts like
    a normal :class:`.Integer` on the Python side.

    """

    __visit_name__ = 'big_integer'
```

BIGINT

```
class BIGINT(BigInteger):

    """The SQL BIGINT type."""

    __visit_name__ = 'BIGINT'
```

But Column(BigInteger) and Column(BIGINT) can both work, both define a bigint in postgresql. How to distinguish them?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51029761/sqlalchemy-boolean-vs-boolean

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They both work, but the `BIGINT` has to be imported from a specific dialect, eg postgres in your case. If you change your database to eg. mysql, you might have problems. With `BigInteger` sqlalchemy with take care of the mapping, depending on the database you are using, so you should prefer this one.

Comment: Is BIGINT really dialet specific? The documentation says it is SQL type:

Bases: sqlalchemy.types.BigInteger
The SQL BIGINT type.

I personally still confused how do I choose SQL type vs sqlalchemy type.

Comment: I think I got it now. BIGINT is for standard SQL type, like other primitive data types, should be supported by most mainstream DBMS. But... not all standard SQL types are widely implemented, e.g. BLOB, DATE, NCHAR, so the sqlalchemy type has its advantage.

Comment: @shiouming: the whole idea of using an ORM is to make the *least specific* decision, and let the ORM choose the best type, depending on your database. According to the documentation `BigInteger` is *typically* mapped to an sql big integer, which BIGINT is always mapped to a big integer (probably a left over from previous sqlalchemy versions). There are also vendor specific versions, eg `mysq.BIGINT` and `postgres.BIGINT`. There's no reason to use them, unless it's for a type supported by *only* as specific to a database (eg `int[]` in postgres)

Comment: Agree, I don't see the need to use dialet specific BIGINT either. I came to this post after realising my codes use mixed of SQL INTEGER and sqlalchemy Integer, I have changed all of them to Integer.